# django-admin.py startproject is ignoring hidden files

Tags: python, django

I'm kinda new in using Django's startproject command from django-admin.py, and amazed with shortage of time that this command gave me. Althought I have one question about it for which I couldn't find answer on official documentation.

In my project skeleton folder which is used to build new project I have two folders with starting `.(dot)`  sing which is used in Linux Os-es like marker for hidden folders. Example:

```
.hiddenFolder
    |
    ----
       |
     file.js
       |
     file.cfg
       |
     file.html
```

once when I hit:

```
django-admin startproject --template 
/home/virt_env/project_env/project_folder/project_skeleton 
--extension py,js,json myNewProject
```

myNewProject gets generated but those hidden folders `.hiddenFolder` and `.anotherHiddenFolder` and all files inside them are not placed inside newly generated project.

It feels like they are ignored and I do not know what should I try to put in command. Is there any flag available that tells to command

> "do not ingnore hidden folders and files"

Or is there any alternative solution?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, there isn't such option in "startproject" command. You can see source:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/templates.py#L129

This is done explicitly.

Comment: Yes, this is not good for me :/... I guess I should develop somekind of workaround for those folders with renaming or something after generation. Thank you for info!

Answer (score 0):

This is possible starting with Django 4.0 ([source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.0/django/core/management/templates.py#L142-L146)). This is what [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-startproject-exclude) says:

> `--exclude DIRECTORIES, -x DIRECTORIES`
>
> Specifies which directories in the project template should be excluded, in addition to `.git` and `__pycache__`. If this option is not provided, directories named `__pycache__` or starting with `.` will be excluded.